# Spring Data JPA Query for inner join table throwing error

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-boot

Spring DATA JPA question... I am trying to write a query to access the data in my sql join table.

I have my join table set up as follows:

```html
@Entity
@Table(name="WritingCompany")
public class WritingCompany {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "companyId")
    private Long id;
//    private String companyName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Join-WritingCo-Carrier",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="writingCo"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="carrier")
    )
    private Set<CarrierAppointment> carriers;


//...getters and setters

}
```

```html
 public class CarrierAppointment {
   
 //  ...
 
   @ManyToMany(
            cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "companyName"
    )
    private Set<WritingCompany> companies;

    public Set<WritingCompany> getCompanies() {
        return companies;
    }

    public void setCompanies(Set<WritingCompany> companies) {
        this.companies = companies;
    }

//...

}
```

I am unsure which class repository I need to write the query for... I am trying to find all the writingCo names from the join table that all have the same carrier id that matches one specific carrier.

The Join Table is set up through writing company but I feel like it should be accessed through CarrierAppointment Repository since I am matching carrier Id's.

This is what I've tried in the CarrierAppointmentrepository and it throws this error (unexpected token: Join near line 1, column 94):

```html
    @Query("Select companyName FROM WritingCompany INNER JOIN CarrierAppointment ON Join-WritingCo-Carrier.carrier= CarrierAppointment.CarrierAppointmentId")
    List<CarrierAppointment> findCarrierAppoinmentFromJoin(CarrierAppointment carrier);
```

I've also tried:

```html
    @Query("SELECT writingCo FROM Join-WritingCo-Carrier WHERE carrier= CarrierAppointment.CarrierAppointmentId")
    List<CarrierAppointment> findCarrierAppoinmentFromJoin(CarrierAppointment carrier);
```

Then I tried this in the writingCompanyRepository which also throws a similar error:

```html
    @Query("Select companyName FROM WritingCompany INNER JOIN CarrierAppointment ON Join-WritingCo-Carrier.carrier= CarrierAppointment.CarrierAppointmentId")
    List<WritingCompany> findAllWithDescriptionQuery(CarrierAppointment carrier);
```

I am having a hard time understanding what this query is saying. Do I ever need to access the columns from the sql join table, or am I just querying around the join table by asking for each class that is making up the join columns in the join table? What is the right part of the statement, after  INNER JOIN stating ? Could someone please provide a deeper explanation of why the query is written so I can figure out why it's not working? I've been reading a lot of inner join examples and just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Your mapping is incorrect. One side of the association is an association between WritingCompany and WritingCompany. The other side is an association between CarrierAppointment and WritingCompany. Also, JPQL never, ever, ever use table names. Only entities and their fields. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join

Comment: I fixed the mapping. Good catch @JBNizet , now just have to figure out the correct way to query.